# MySQL index for non-empty string query

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have the table `posts` and its column `descr` in my application. And I need to query posts where description is not empty, but the table has too many rows, so I need to add an index. What is the best way to add this index?

Table structure (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255),
    descr VARCHAR(1024),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) engine=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Example of query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE descr <> '';
```

I don't want to create an index on the whole `descr` column, because it will be huge overhead.

Also I know variant about adding another column `is_empty_descr BOOLEAN` and add index to it. This solution I will use if no other variants would be found.

I tried to add `INDEX( descr(1) )`, but I couldn't find the way how to use it:

- `desrc <> ''` - index is not used
- `LEFT(desrc, 1) = ''` - index is not used
- `SUBSTR(desrc, 0, 1) = ''` - index is not used
- `desrc LIKE 'a%'` - index is used! But this is totally different case

In all my examples I see something like this:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM posts WHERE descr <> '';
+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| ALL  | descr_1       | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   42 | Using where |
+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

(I omited some result columns, because the table is too wide for this site)

Even if I pass `FORCE index (descr_1)` result will be the same.

Comment: "but I couldn't find the way how to use it." - eh, by performing your query using `EXPLAIN` to see whether the index is actually used would be a way.

Comment: Of course, but mysql does not use this index in almost all cases that i test:

`desrc <> ''` - index is not used;
`LEFT(desrc, 1) = ''`  - index is not used;
`SUBSTR(caption, 0, 1) = ''`  - index is not used;

Comment: Is that because there's another index on that table which is used instead?

Comment: No, mysql simply ignoring this index, see example I added above.

Comment: Well, that's rather unfortunate then; the workaround by using a boolean value it is then (unless someone comes up with something brilliant), you could use triggers to make sure the values don't go out of sync.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can add a description on a prefix of a string using this syntax:

```
create index idx_posts_descr1 on posts(descr(1));
```

You should test this to see if the index is used for that particular `where` clause, though.